# ANOVA results discrepancy between R and SPSS

Tags: r, anova, spss

I ran into problems when trying to double check SPSS ANOVA calculations with R. I am aware of the difference in defaults concerning the Sum of Squares, therefore I followed guidelines for aligning SPSS and R results. After failing to get equivalent results I used a toy data set to make sure it is not a problem specific to the data involved.

Here is the toy data:

```
Crit    A   B
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   1   0
4   1   0
4   1   0
5   1   0
6   1   0
6   1   0
7   0   1
8   0   1
9   0   1
10  0   1
11  0   1
12  0   0
13  0   0
12  0   0
```

When running the ANOVA using SPSS (24.0.0.0, 64-bit) I use the Syntax:

```
UNIANOVA Crit BY A B
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /DESIGN=A B A*B.
```

This results in the (shortened) output:

```
Tests of Between-Subjects Effects                   

    Dependent Variable:   Crit 

Source  SS      df     MS     F      Sig.
Itc.  630.208    1 630.208  408.784 .000
A     191.690    1 191.690  124.339 .000
B      35.208    1  35.208   22.838 .000
A * B    .023    1    .023     .015 .905
Error  18.500   12   1.542
```

In R (RStudio V. 1.1.383, R 3.4.3), I used the "car" package, using the code:

```
simpledata<-read.table("simpleData.txt",sep="\t", header=T)
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
model=lm(Crit ~ B+A+B:A, data = simpledata)
Anova(model, type="3")
```

This should produce equivalent numbers based on multiple guides found online.
Instead, I find the output:

```
Response: Crit
            Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 456.33  1 296.000 8.026e-10 ***
A           117.56  1  76.252 1.517e-06 ***
B            20.83  1  13.514  0.003172 ** 
A:B           0.02  1   0.015  0.904503    
Residuals    18.50 12
```

As can be seen, the results for the interaction and the error are identical, but nothing else aligns. This matches the comparison for my original problem. Notice that I receive the following output when changing the SS to "2":

```
Response: Crit
           Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
A         197.890  1 128.361 9.151e-08 ***
B          35.852  1  23.255 0.0004174 ***
A:B         0.023  1   0.015 0.9045030    
Residuals  18.500 12
```

This is closer but not identical to the SPSS output (but it should not be, as SPSS uses Type III).

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a satisfactory solution? For psychologists this should be a deeply concerning question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all good. You just need to tell R that you want `A` and `B` to be factors (if you want to do an *Analysis of Variance*). Currently, R treats `A` and `B` as numeric variables (or, more precisely, as integers), which will run a *multiple linear regression analysis*.

```
class(simpledata$A)
# [1] "integer"
class(simpledata$B)
# [1] "integer"

# CONVERT A AND B TO FACTORS
simpledata$Af <- as.factor(simpledata$A)
simpledata$Bf <- as.factor(simpledata$B)

# FIT MODEL WITH FACTOR VARIABLES
model=lm(Crit ~ Bf + Af + Bf:Af, data = simpledata)
Anova(model, type = "3")

#Anova Table (Type III tests)
#Response: Crit
#            Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
#(Intercept) 630.21  1 408.784 1.229e-10 ***
#Bf           35.21  1  22.838 0.0004494 ***
#Af          191.69  1 124.339 1.091e-07 ***
#Bf:Af         0.02  1   0.015 0.9045030    
#Residuals    18.50 12
```

Comment: This solved both problems (the toy and the real-world one). I still wonder how many results out there are based on surprising variants...

Comment: @jank That's a good question and it looks like others have indeed ran into this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226069/when-are-factors-necessary-appropriate-in-r). This highlights again that cross-checking your results can save you life ;) - especially when switching from one statistical software package to another.